# GXT MessageBox - customize buttons

Tags: gxt

how can i customize the buttons in gxt MessageBox. 
so instead of Ok and cancel i can have different lables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
((Button)box.getDialog().getButtonBar().getItem(0)).setText("changed");
```

Comment: sorry i got a better answer from sencha http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?177584-Customize-MessageBox&p=723266#post723266

Answer (score 0):

MessageBox is just a helper class for creating common Dialogs with, for example, YESOK buttons and others. 
MessageBox.show() is:

```
public void show() {
    dialog = getDialog();
    dialog.show();
}
```

getDialog() - creates dialog with your predefined parameters.

If you want to really customize your buttons - set icons, change text, add more buttons like "print, export..." - extend Dialog, call setButtons(""); in constructor and add your buttons addButton(new MyCustomButton);

Also, you are free to get details in MessageBox source.